# Get Users Comment From Mysql using Php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to allow a user to comment on a profile on my website. I have the following **php -- updated**:

```
<?php
// Insert Comments into Database that user provides
$comm = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['addComment']);
$pID4 = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'pID', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$cID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['courseInfoDD']);
        $username = "###";
        $password = "####";
        $pdo4 = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=###', $username, $password);
        $pdo4->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$sth3 = $pdo3->prepare('
        INSERT INTO Comment (info, pID, cID)
        VALUES(:info, :pID, :cID)
             ');
$sth3->execute(array(
            ':info' => $comm, ':pID' => $pID3, ':cID' => $cID
        ));
?>
```

**DB Table "Comment"**
http://postimage.org/image/16sbr0jd0/   (Moderator please convert this to show image, please)

**HTML:**

```
<input type='text' id='addComment' name='addComment' tabindex='3' value='Enter comment' />
```

**Error Given:**

`No pID specified` . When I try to insert a comment.

Answer (score 4):

You are using single-quotes in your insert statement :

```
$sth3 = $pdo3->prepare('
    INSERT INTO Comment (info, pID, cID)
    VALUES($comm, $pID3, $cID)
');
```

With those simple quotes, **`$comm` will not be evaluated** -- and the literal `$comm` string will be sent to the database -- resulting in something you probably don't quite expect.

If you want variables to be interpolated, you should use [**double-quotes around your string**][1].

But, **as you are trying to use prepared statements, that's not what you should do**, actually.

Instead, **you should use placeholders in the statement** -- and, then, bind those to your data, when executing the statement.

Your `prepare` would look a bit like this, I suppose :

```
$sth3 = $pdo3->prepare('
    INSERT INTO Comment (info, pID, cID)
    VALUES(:comm, :pID3, :cID)
');
```

Note the `:comm`, `:pID3`, and `:cID` placeholders.

And, then, when executing the statement, you'll actually pass some real data, to correspond to the placeholders :

$sth3->execute(array(
':comm' => $comm,
':pID3' => $pID3,
':cID' => $cID,
));

Additional note : as you are using prepared statements, **you don't have to use `mysql_real_escape_string()`** *(which is not a PDO-related function, BTW, and should only be used when working with `mysql_*` functions)* : the escaping is dealt by the prepared statement mecanism itself.

Comment: See My updated code, this 'prepare' method doesnt seem to be grabbing the pID in the line '$pID3 = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'pID', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);' where $pID3 is prepared as var.

Comment: WHy isnt this getting the pID?

Answer (score 1):

The parameters to the PDO prepared statement should be used like this:

```
$sth3 = $pdo3->prepare('
        INSERT INTO Comment (info, pID, cID)
        VALUES(:info, :pID, :cID)
             ');
$sth3->execute(array(
            ':info' => $comm, ':pID' => $pID3, ':cID' => $cID
        ));
```

First set up the "slots" for the values, then supply them when you run the query.

Comment: If I try this and try to submit a comment, it throws an error that there is no "pID" found for the 'professor'. Should I added this in the query 'WHERE pID = ?' ?

Comment: @user700070: No, WHERE is not used in inserts. Looks like the pID should be a part of your URL's GET variables, as in `/addcomment.php?pID=3`.

Comment: @user700070: Did you add the `?pID=3` to the form's action? That should do it. Although I'd recommend you move the pID to the POST fields as well for clarity's sake.

Answer (score 0):

$variables in single quote strings are not being processed. Use double quotes instead and add quotes for the SQL statement itself:

```
$sth3 = $pdo3->prepare("
        INSERT INTO Comment (info, pID, cID)
        VALUES('$comm', '$pID3', '$cID')
             ");
```

Comment: Considering he is using prepared statements, the values should not be injected into the query -- instead, they should be bound when executing the statement.

Answer (score 0):

our problem has nothing to do not with mysql not with comments.

It's basic PHP strings syntax.

Use double quotes if you want variables to be interpreted in a string.

However, you shouldn't add variables into query directly, but rather bins them

Comment: It is not calling the pID though, if I test this.