# Pull data from Mysql Into Dropdown

Tags: php, sql

**UPDATED

```
  <?php
    // Get select box of courses to comment on 
    $pID3 = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'pID', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
            $username = "###";
            $password = "###";
            $pdo3 = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=###', $username, $password);
            $pdo3->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    $sth3 = $pdo3->prepare('
        SELECT C.prefix, C.code
        FROM Department D, Course C
        WHERE D.dID = C.dID
        **AND pID = ?**

    ');
            $sth3->execute(array(
                $pID3
            ));
    ?>

            <html>
                    <?php
                    echo "<form action='inc/q/prof.php' method='post'>
                        <select id='courseInfoDD' name='courseID' tabindex='1'>";
                    ?>
                          <?php
                            while($row3 = $sth3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                              echo "<option>".$row3['prefix'].", ".$row3['code']."</option>";
                            }
                          ?>
                          <?php 
                        echo "</select>";
                        ?>
            </html>
```

Okay, so right now its pulled all courses regardless of the pID or (Professor ID). I added a statement in the select saying where pID = ? , since the pID is in the url of the page. But now it throws and error about pID???

Query:

```
SELECT C.prefix, C.code
FROM Department D, Course C, Professor P
WHERE pID = ?
AND D.dID = C.dID
AND D.dID = p.dID;
```

- Phpmyadmin error

  : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? AND D.dID = C.dID AND D.dID = p.dID LIMIT 0, 30' at line 3

Db Img: http://postimage.org/image/24gdqab8k/

and

http://postimage.org/image/24gfdtnqc/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Users Comment From Mysql using Php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605907/get-users-comment-from-mysql-using-php)

Comment: What is the difference between "updated code" and "test.php"? Your question is kind of a mess :-(

Comment: So, I dragged all the files into one file as test.php  to get the output to show, but its still showing the value pulled as "Array"... ?

Comment: See my comment below yours, on my answer. You're trying to output an array with a single "echo" statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. You need to follow some basic debugging steps. Here's exactly how to fix the problem:

1. First, my #1 guess about what's going on.... reading over your code, an empty data set will produce an empty select box. So start with the most simple: have you tried your SQL query directly on the database (i.e. with something like phpMyAdmin or the SQL command-line tool)? Be sure it works and (just as importantly) returns data.
2. If that works, then move the fetch call up into the PHP at the top, and just fetch the data and echo it to the screen (in other words, remove all the HTML). This will at least show you if it's fetching data from the database and your PHP PDO calls are correct.
3. Finally, if that doesn't seem like anything is wrong, find out if the PDO library is throwing a SQL error. Maybe it can't connect to the database; maybe your query returns empty rows. Very simple:

   ```
   print_r($sth3->errorInfo());
   ```
4. Have you done a "view source" on the output? Is it writing out any of the option tags? bensiu's answer is correct, in that you need double quotes, not single quotes, around your "print" statement.

I promise that if you follow these steps, your code will work ;-)

Comment: Eric #1, works fine. See The file contents about for **test.php** .

Comment: Fantastic! Did you try #2 and #3 and #4 yet? ;-)

Comment: #2 - outputs all options as '$row' ... see test.php above.

Comment: I changed the quote around $row like "$row" in the echo, but it just displays all option as 'array' now...

Comment: Ok, so PDO is returning an associative array for each row. In other words: each row has two values (prefix and code) in an array and you have one echo statement trying to display that array. Try changing the echo statement to: echo "<option>".$row3['prefix'].", ".$row3['code']."</option>";

Comment: This works, however, its pulling all courses in the db. I need it to pull based on pID and I added a clause to the where statement and it throws an error. Is this an error in PDO ?

Comment: The error message says it all: "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pID' in 'where clause'" -- do you have a pID column? First rule of debugging when you get a SQL error, try the query directly on the DB (using a tool like phpMyAdmin or the SQL command line etc.).

Comment: Good call. I added a picture of my db above and the query im trying

Comment: Ok. So now you have a new question... about the SQL error you're getting. "pID = ?" is not a valid SQL statement. You need to give SQL a pID that you're looking for. I'll give you a hint: if it's in the URL, look at the PHP $_REQUEST superglobal variable.

Answer (score 0):

If that

```
<select id='courseInfoDD' name='courseID' tabindex='1'>
  while($row3 = $sth3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<option>$row3</option>";
  }
</select>
```

really is all your HTML, then your problem is, that that’d HTML and not PHP. You wanted to make it PHP, right?

```
<select id='courseInfoDD' name='courseID' tabindex='1'>
  <?php
    while($row3 = $sth3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      echo '<option>$row3</option>';
    }
  ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print "<option>{$row3}</option>";
```

or

```
echo "<option>$row3</option>";
```

double quotes and you are missing `<?php` and `?>' tags

```
<select id='courseInfoDD' name='courseID' tabindex='1'>
 <?php
   while($row3 = $sth3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     echo "<option>$row3</option>";
   }
 ?>
</select>
```